# LESS client side not working for me

Tags: less

Instructions to use LESS on the client side are as easy as it can get.. yet still for some reason it's not working for me.![enter image description here][1]

I get this error on Firebug's console:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbIJP.jpg

If I go to the URL of the home.less file as written there, I see the contents (they're basically the same CSS I was using until now, renamed, since I'm just starting to use LESS and haven't done anything yet with it).

The only javascript in the code (again, same URL as in the code) is just less-1.3.0.min.js renamed.

This is the full HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es_ES" />

    <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="http://domain.dev/css/home.less?id=1" />
        <script src="http://domain.dev/js/generated/home.js?id=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**SOLUTION / EDIT:** OK I figured out what was the problem. Apparently LESS doesn't work client side (with less.js and all) if the .less file you're referencing on your LINK tag is not on the same domain (even different subdomain will not work, as was my case). I didn't know LESS had this limitation as CSS doesn't have it. They should warn about this in the documentation.

Comment: I think, since less.js is a client-side javascript, the problem is in [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)... JS can't access file from a domain, different from it's origin!

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @drinchev less.js is a client-side javascript so you will end up in a cross domain issue. This can be fixed by enabeling CORS, see: http://enable-cors.org/. On the domain where home.less has been installed, the server should send an  Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header.

less.js loads the less files with a XMLHttpRequests which supports CORS for most modern browsers see http://caniuse.com/#search=cors. More details can be found at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/